# Vertically aligning

Tags: css, alignment

How do I vertically align the element in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BED9f.png)?

```
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px; margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    } 
   #headercontainer {
    background-color:gray;
    }
    #headercontainer ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    nav {
    margin: 0px 10%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    #floatedright {
    float: right;
    }
    #floatedright a {
    color: darkgreen;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
   #floatedright > li {
    float: left;
    }
    #piercarla {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: white;
    font-family: cursive;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <section id="headercontainer">
      <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="Piercarla">Piercarla</a></li>
            <section id="floatedright">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </section>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </section>
```

Comment: You can add some magin-top to your menu, for example with your values, nav {margin: 15px 10% 0; }

Answer (score 0):

[you can resolve your problem using this.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

I think vertical-align: middle; is suitable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just give some class to the three list items Home,Events,Contact `class="m"`, and then style them to give `margin-left` `margin-right` to vertically align them accordingly.